# How to call a java web service using JBOSS

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, webservice-client, jboss6.x

I need some help to create and call a java web service in java.
I developed a java web service using JBOSS in eclips.

Now i wana call this web service as client side.

i need the way to call a web service like create a call, service , etc..

or please provide any videos to learn web service using jboss

Thanks to all in advance..

Comment: You should probably read the JBoss documentation.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Quick+Start

Comment: Were you able to find a good resource to implement a client.

Answer (score 0):

[Jboss Webservices Client Tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/WebServices_Guide/en-US/html_single/#JBossWS-UserGuide_Web_Service_Clients)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[Eclipse JBoss Web Service Step by Step](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8TzX46bA1M)